# How can I sort historical data in a list in order to calculate monthly averages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python beginner and I am struggling with sorting a list which is an output of stock historical data of a company.so far I have retrieved the file from the url given and I have printed the data into a one long list with date, open, close,volume etc.how can I get about sorting it out and be able to calculate the average prices. please help

```
import httplib2

GOOGLE_URL = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr7cu2kui654kgz/googlePrices.csvdl=1"

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")

headers, prices = h.request(GOOGLE_URL)


dataList = prices.decode().strip('\n').split(',')

dataList = dataList[1:]

print (dataList)
```

Comment: Read about `list.sort()` function, especially about the `key` parameter.

Comment: Also, this specific task is greatly simplified if you are able to use something like [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: I am trying to stay away from pandas, am still in the process of learning it. and I will look at list.sort(). thanks guys